# VirtualBox 5.0.26 (Ubuntu 16.04) VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion, ubuntu-16.04

To make use of Genymotion I need to install VirtualBox 5.0.26 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I need to create a Host-only Network Adapter, but when I do,  I get the following error message:

> VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl
>   failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic.
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: 
>   HostNetworkInterfaceWrap Interface:  IHostNetworkInterface
>   {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}

**Update**

I just tried to create a Host-only Network Interface with the VirtualBox Version **5.0.28** and **5.1.14** and VirtualBox throws the same error.

So it seems to be a general problem?

Answer (score 4):

After trying and trying, it was installing the virtualbox guest additions that solved my problemL

```
sudo apt-get -y install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Comment: this resolved an issue I had when running the `docker-machine create` command and receiving the following error: `VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guessing, but did you manage to specify the right network adapter (or, the way VB is supposed to use it)? It looks like it VirtualBox can't find it. Could you please show how the VB adapter is set up in the settings?

EDIT: If you have a graphical user interface with you VB, I suggest you going to settings and choose the section that's about the network adapter. This could help you setting it up the right way: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox

Comment: can you send me a link where it is described, how i can specify the right network adapter? i havent done anything besides installing virtualbox. after that i tried to create a network interface

Comment: i also tried following these steps, but with no success http://askubuntu.com/questions/787471/virtualbox-5-is-unable-to-create-a-host-only-adapter-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I have edited my answer you can check the link that's in

Comment: i am using a graphical user interface. when trying to create a host-only network interface with the graphical user interface i get the error.

Comment: Do you still have this error when trying the other options?

Comment: i found the problem. please see my answer. thx for your help anyway

Comment: I am not really used to this kind of things even if I'm an Ubuntu user, anyway I am glad you found out how to troubleshoot it.